# strip HTML tags with certain content from string

Tags: php, regex

```
$text = "<p>keep me</p> <p>strip me &nbsp;</p>
$pattern = "/<[^\/>]*>(\&nbsp\;)*<\/[^>]*>/"; 
$text =  preg_replace($pattern, '', $text);
```

Hi, I need to strip "quasi-empty" p tags from a html string. there's always only a &nbsp; as a trigger in the p element. how can I strip it with regex?

Comment: Obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Is there anything else in the p-tag but the `&nbsp;`? (your example has `strip me ` in there, but your text says it's only the `&nbsp;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pattern will match all `<p> </p>` blocks that include `&nbsp;` along with any accompanying text, as per your example.

```
$text = "<p>keep me</p> <p>strip me &nbsp;</p>";
$pattern = "/<p>[^<]*&nbsp\;[^<]*<\/p>/"; 
$output =  preg_replace($pattern, '', $text);
```

If you actually want it to only strip out `<p> </p>` blocks with `&nbsp;` and spaces, use the following pattern instead:

```
$pattern = "/<p>(\s*&nbsp\;\s*)+<\/p>/";
```

If you want to only strip out `<p> </p>` blocks that have an `&nbsp;` and up to a certain number of characters, use the following (setting the `$maxChars` variables as you see fit):

```
$maxCharsBefore = 10;
$maxCharsAfter = 10;
$pattern = "/<p>[^<]{0,".$maxCharsBefore."}&nbsp\;[^<]{0,".$maxCharsAfter."}<\/p>/";
```

Comment: cool, that one behaves the way I want. thanks to all the posters!

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "<p>keep me</p> <p>strip me &nbsp;</p>";
str_replace('&nbsp;','',$text);
```

<strike>job done</strike>

Yo have a lot of learning to do: http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html

---

```
<?php
$text = "<p>keep me</p> <p>strip me &nbsp;</p><div class=\"someclass\">div</div>";
$newtext = "";
preg_match_all("/(\<.*?>.*?<\/.*?>)/",$text,$matches);
foreach($matches[0] as $tag)
{
    if(!strstr($tag,'&nbsp;'))
    {
        $newtext .= $tag;
    }
}
echo $newtext;
?>
```

Comment: I think he want's to remove the p-tags as well... but yeah.

Comment: I suspect that fails on nested tags.

Comment: yep, but i just gave him a snip for the string he posted, he needs a DOM traverse tool to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
$text  = preg_replace("!<p>(?:&nbsp;)*</p>!", "", $text);
```

Comment: In wich way ? According to OP, he wants to remove p tags that only contain &nbsp;